# Changing files (using sed) in Packer script leaves files unchanged

Tags: bash, docker, sed, packer

currently I am looking into building a build-pipeline using packer and docker.
This is my packer.json:

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "docker",
    "image": "php:7.0-apache",
    "commit": true
  }],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "./",
      "destination": "/var/www/html/"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": [
        "chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html",
        "sed '/<Directory \\/var\\/www\\/>/,/<\\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride all/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf",
        "sed '/<VirtualHost/,/<\\/VirtualHost>/ s/DocumentRoot \\/var\\/www\\/html/DocumentRoot \\/var\\/www\\/html\\/web/' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The Shell Script inside the `provisioners` section contains some sed commands for changing the `AllowOverride` and `DocumentRoot` variables inside the apache config.

When packer runs this script it is working all fine and I am getting a positive sed output, so sed seems to work fine. But in the docker image the files are unchanged.
Copying the files in the `file` provisioner is working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please post expected output for same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're missing `-i` (or `--in-place`) flag in your sed commands. Try with:

```
"sed -i <expression> <file>"
```